# Jython, ImageInfo

Tags: image, jython

I trying to use ImageInfo and Jython to get information from a image on my harddrive.

I have imported the module fine but keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: setInput(): expected 2 args; got 1
```

And this is the code I am trying to use:

```
filename = "C:\\image.jpg"
img = ImageInfo.setInput(filename)
```

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing argument Jython complains about is the ImageInfo object itself, which doesn't exist yet. You must construct it first. So:

```
filename = "C:\\image.jpg"
ii = ImageInfo()
img = ii.setInput(filename)
```

or

```
filename = "C:\\image.jpg"
img = ImageInfo().setInput(filename)
```

may work also.